# delete from table1,table2,table3 where?

Tags: sql, mysql, multi-table-delete

If all tables I want to delete from have the column gamer_id

can i do a delete from table1, table2, table3 where gamer_id = 123?

or is there a different syntax?

Comment: Which RDBMS?  It can be done in Postgres but not SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL supports [multi-table deletes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
  JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t2.gamer_id = t1.gamer_id
  JOIN TABLE_3 t3 ON t3.gamer_id = t1.gamer_id
 WHERE t1.gamer_id = 123
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it without a join?

Comment: @Hailwood: I don't see the need--the join will include the rows in each respective table where the `gamer_id` is what you specify.  Or is the issue that it's possible the `gamer_id` doesn't exist in one of the three tables?

Comment: Its more a performance issue, as there will be approx 80 rows in each table that matches, does that not mean it will do 80^3 joins = 512 000 joins?

Comment: @Hailwood: I read that as 80 rows per table, times 3 = 240 rows.  You don't have to use multi-table deletion, and process the deletion a table at a time.

Comment: I thought it did a join on every row, so would it not be to the power of?

Comment: @Hailwood: No, it depends on the number of rows associated in the joined tables.  If there's only one row in each table with the same `gamer_id`, then the resultset is one row.  If one of those tables has two and the rest have one row--the resultset will be two rows.

Comment: Cheers,
Im about to ask another db related question so keep a look out ;)
Have an upvote 8D